# How to grab a value from cache and pass it to an SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sharepoint-designer, query, sql, cache, parameter

I am designing a website that queries an SQL database when opened, providing a list of bills for the given user. I am using a custom SQL query with a Data Source/Data View and in the Command & Parameters window I have also specified a parameter 'userName' from the Cache value 'IDSID' (which is available when logged into the website). However, when I try to view the website, no results are output. It has the title of the View and 'Rows:' but no actual results. I even included a 'PRINT @userName' command at the end of the stored procedure so it seems to me that Sharepoint is not correctly grabbing the information from cache. I don't really know where to go from here as I am very new to Sharepoint and Google doesn't seem to provide much answers for me (at least, not that I can see). I would really appreciate any and all help - anything I might have missed? If you need any more information please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
<ParameterBinding Name="LogonUser" Location="ServerVariable(LOGON_USER)"/>
```

These are few [IIS Server Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(VS.85).aspx)

`AUTH_USER`, `LOGON_USER`, `REMOTE_USER`.. that you can use..

Reference

[Getting the Current User Name or ID in SharePoint using SharePoint Designer (no code)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshuag/archive/2008/06/03/getting-the-current-user-name-or-id-in-sharepoint-using-sharepoint-designer-no-code.aspx)

[Send current user's parameter to External Content Type](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45525/send-current-users-parameter-to-external-content-type)

Comment: That unfortunately did not work, but Server Variables aren't even an option in the actual Command & Parameters window for me :/

Comment: Did you try the last link ?

Comment: I cannot create an External Content Type on this type of Sharepoint website (I think it is because of the way Sharepoint as a whole is set up for end users in this organisation)